# how do I check for underlying null value using linq to sql?

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I know that if you query a linq-to-sql record (ie row in DB/object) with a null field, then linq to SQL will allow you to access the null value without a null reference exception, like this: `Dim myValue as String = myRecord.Nullfield`.

But I WANT to query records where the field in the underlying DB is null.

How do I do that with LINQ?

```
(From l In myDB.myTable Where l.Program.Equals(DBNull.Value) Select l).Count //Unexpected type code: DBNull
```

What is the syntax that I am looking for?

Comment: I think the LINQ db adapters can do that for you: `Where l.Program == null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `== null` (or whatever the VB.NET equivalent is). No more `DBNull`. Yay!

Comment: what is the VB equivalent. that is what i am looking for

Comment: The key to the answer was comparing with null. Finding the C# syntax is your job to figure out. It is well withing your capabilities so don't give up so easily.

Answer (score 0):

See [null semantics mismatching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386909.aspx) article on MSDN.
Generally, you can use either

```
(From l In myDB.myTable Where l.Program.Equals(null) Select l).Count
```

or

```
(From l In myDB.myTable Where l.Program == null Select l).Count
```