# LINQ how to handle null values

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

sorry for bad english;

my code;

```
Dim otherDT As DataTable = retDS1.Tables(0)           
Dim dt As New DataTable

dt.Columns.Add("COGRAFI_BOLGE_ADI")
dt.Columns.Add("Count")

Dim query = (From dr In (From d In otherDT.AsEnumerable Select New With {.COGRAFI_BOLGE_ADI = d("COGRAFI_BOLGE_ADI")}) Select dr.COGRAFI_BOLGE_ADI Distinct)

For Each colName As String In query
  Dim cName = colName
  Dim cCount = (From row In otherDT.Rows Select row Where row("COGRAFI_BOLGE_ADI").ToString = cName).Count
  dt.Rows.Add(colName, cCount)
Next

GridView1.DataSource = dt
GridView1.DataBind()
```

Some rows contain a null value;
How do I handle null lines?

Output:

```
Marmara 40
Ege     10
Akdeniz 2
...
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580008/how-do-i-check-for-underlying-null-value-using-linq-to-sql

Answer (score 0):

Not really clear what you are asking, but are you looking for something like this:

```
Dim otherDT As DataTable = retDS1.Tables(0)           
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt.Columns.Add("COGRAFI_BOLGE_ADI")
dt.Columns.Add("Count")

Dim query = (From dr In (From d In otherDT.AsEnumerable 
                         Select New With {.COGRAFI_BOLGE_ADI = d("COGRAFI_BOLGE_ADI")})         
             Select dr.COGRAFI_BOLGE_ADI Distinct)

For Each colName As String In query
  Dim cName As String = colName
  Dim cCount As Integer = (From row In otherDT.Rows 
                           Select row 
                           Where row IsNot Nothing AndAlso
                               row("COGRAFI_BOLGE_ADI") IsNot Nothing AndAlso 
                               row("COGRAFI_BOLGE_ADI").ToString = cName).Count
  If cCount > 0 Then
      dt.Rows.Add(colName, cCount)
  End If
Next

GridView1.DataSource = dt
GridView1.DataBind()
```